# Cauchy derivation theorem of integrals demonstration

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, induction, cauchy-integral-formula

I am studing the cauchy derivates theorem and there is one step which i don't understand.
When we are proving for $f^{(n)}$ for math induction.

The hipothese are:
$$f^{(n-1)}(z):=\frac{(n-1)!}{2 \pi i} \int_{\partial D} \frac{f(\xi)}{(\xi - z )^n}d \xi$$

The step is:

\begin{align}
f^{(n)}&=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f^{(n-1)}(z+h)-f^{(n-1)}(z)}{h}
\\&=\frac{(n-1)!}{2 \pi i} \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \bigg[ \int_{\partial D} \frac{f(\xi)}{(\xi - z - h )^n}d \xi - \int_{\partial D} \frac{f(\xi)}{(\xi - z )^n}d \xi\bigg]
\\&=\frac{(n-1)!}{2 \pi i} \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \int_{\partial D} f(\xi)\frac{(\xi -z)^n-(\xi -z-h)^n}{(\xi - z - h )^n(\xi-z)^n}d \xi &(1)
\\ &=\frac{(n-1)!}{2 \pi i} \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \int_{\partial D} f(\xi)\frac{nh(\xi -z)^{n-1}-\cdots}{(\xi - z - h )^n(\xi-z)^n}d \xi  &(2)
\\ &=\frac{(n-1)!}{2 \pi i} \int_{\partial D}\lim_{h \to 0} \bigg[ f(\xi)\frac{n-\cdots}{(\xi - z - h )^n(\xi-z)} \bigg]d \xi  &(3)
\\ &\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \vdots
\end{align}

I don't understand the step from $(1)$ to $(2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding the second numerator fraction term using the [Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) when going from $(1)$ to $(2)$ gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
& (\xi - z)^n - \left((\xi - z) - h\right)^n \\
& = (\xi - z)^n - \left((\xi - z)^n - nh(\xi - z)^{n-1} + \ldots\right) \\
& = (\xi - z)^n - (\xi - z)^n + nh(\xi - z)^{n-1} - \ldots \\
& = nh(\xi - z)^{n-1} - \ldots
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$